# Pattern matching and replacement in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am not familiar at all with regular expressions, and would like to do pattern matching and replacement in R.

I would like to replace the pattern `#1`, `#2` in the vector: `original = c("#1", "#2", "#10", "#11")` with each value of the vector `vec = c(1,2)`.

The result I am looking for is the following vector: `c("1", "2", "#10", "#11")`. I am not sure how to do that. I tried doing:

```
for(i in 1:2) {
    pattern = paste("#", i, sep = "")
    original = gsub(pattern, vec[i], original, fixed = TRUE)
}
```

but I get :

```
#> original
#[1] "1"  "2"  "10" "11"
```

instead of: `"1" "2" "#10" "#11"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option using `gsubfn`:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("^#([1-2])$",  I, original)   ## Function substituting
[1] "1"   "2"   "#10" "#11"
```

Or if you want to explicitly use the values of your vector , using vec values:

```
gsubfn("^#[1-2]$",  as.list(setNames(vec,c("#1", "#2"))), original)
```

Or formula notation equivalent to function notation:

```
gsubfn("^#([1-2])$",  ~ x, original)   ## formula substituting
```

Comment: Thank you!! But for some reason, when I try using the expression `"^#1$"` to replace the pattern `#1`, it does not work! I am soo confused..

Comment: This is what I have tried for **`#1`**: `gsub(paste("^#", i, "$", sep = ""), 1, original)` and `gsubfn(paste("^#", i, "$", sep = ""), 1, original)`, but none work :S

Comment: `gsubfn("^#([1-2])$",  I, original)` **I** here is the "capital letter i" as Identity not 1.

Comment: it works now!! For some reason, I had an additional space in my vector that was messing things up!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Specify that you are matching the entire string from start (`^`) to end (`$`).

Here, I've matched exactly the conditions you are looking at in this example, but I'm guessing you'll need to extend it:

```
> gsub("^#([1-2])$", "\\1", original)
[1] "1"   "2"   "#10" "#11"
```

So, that's basically, "from the start, look for a hash symbol followed by either the exact number one or two. The one or two should be just one digit (that's why we don't use `*` or `+` or something) and also ends the string. Oh, and capture that one or two because we want to 'backreference' it."

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain to me what `"\\1"` means? How does that relate to the replacement values in `vec = c(1,2)`? Thanks a lot

Comment: Than you. The think is my example is very simplistic. However, in my practical case, I need to explicitely use the values of the `vec` vector for replacement, not just drop the `#` sign. Would you please be able to generalize this formula?

Comment: @AnandaMahto so "capture" is `()` and "backreference" is `"\\1"`?

Comment: @zx8754, about to get on a bus, so I'm going to cop-out and just [share a link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) that can probably explain it better than I ever could anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different take that uses *zero width negative lookahead assertion* (what a mouthful!). This is the `(?!...)` which matches `#` at the start of a string as long as it is not followed by whatever is in `...`. In this case two (or equivalently, more as long as they are contiguous) digits. It replaces them with nothing.

```
gsub( "^#(?![0-9]{2})" , "" , original , perl = TRUE )
[1] "1"   "2"   "#10" "#11"
```